# source address chosen in case of multiple IPv4 addresses

Tags: ip, routing

I have following four IPv4 addresses configured to `eth0` interface:

```
# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:41:54:01:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.1/24 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.2.2/30 scope global eth0
    inet 10.10.10.128/24 scope global secondary eth0
    inet 10.10.10.127/24 scope global secondary eth0
#
```

Now if I send traffic to any(10.10.10.1, 192.168.2.2, 10.10.10.128 or 10.10.10.127) of those addresses from IP address 10.10.11.1, then despite the fact that I have specified the source IP to be 10.10.10.127:

```
# ip route show match 10.10.11.1
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0  src 10.10.10.127 
#
```

..my machine sends out packets with the same source IP which was used as a destination IP, e.g. if I execute `ping 10.10.10.128 source 10.10.11.1` in a remote machine, then my machine sends out replies with source address 10.10.10.128:

```
16:11:02.478607 00:19:e2:9e:ec:00 > 00:16:41:54:01:93, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 114: 10.10.11.1 > 10.10.10.128: ICMP echo request, id 34, seq 4, length 80
16:11:02.478616 00:16:41:54:01:93 > 00:19:e2:9e:ec:00, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 114: 10.10.10.128 > 10.10.11.1: ICMP echo reply, id 34, seq 4, length 80
```

In which situation `src` address specified in routing table has affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system always responds to traffic with the address the traffic was sent to.

If you ping `10.10.10.128`, and then receive response traffic from `10.10.10.127`, your system is going to see this other traffic and discard it. Your system has no clue who `10.10.10.127` is, and why it's trying to talk to you.

However if the system that has both `10.10.10.127` and `10.10.10.128` on it tries to initiate communication with an another host, then it will use routing rules to determine the appropriate source address.